# MYSQL WHERE NOT query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I'm working on a project where teachers can assign badges to students, it's similar to an achievement system.

Now I'm trying to  get an overview of students who DON'T have a specific badge, but the queries I use are not working.

I made a table called StudentHasBadge, in which the `studentnumber` and `badge_id` are saved.

Example:
I want to show a list of students (s.studentnumber, s.firstname, s.lastname) that doens't have the "English: Reading" badge.

I use the following query:

(English: Reading has badge_id 61 in my database)

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.studentnumber, s.firstname, s.lastname 
FROM students s INNER JOIN student_has_badge shb 
ON s.studentnumber = shb.studentnumber 
WHERE NOT shb.badge_id = 61
```

As results I also get students who earned the badge

I also tried `!=` instead of `WHERE NOT`, but it doesn't give me a different result

Comment: Just to explain the results you were getting; your query is asking for the students who earned a badge other than badge 61. That includes students that earned badge 61 and at least one other badge. As for answers, I am seconding Gordon's; it's the most straightforward and likely has the best performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and check for no match:

```
SELECT s.studentnumber, s.firstname, s.lastname
FROM students s LEFT JOIN
     student_has_badge shb
     ON s.studentnumber = shb.studentnumber AND shb.badge_id = 61
WHERE shb.studentnumber IS NULL;
```

Comment: Just a question though, why do you look for a studentnumber that is 0?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.studentnumber, s.firstname, s.lastname 
FROM students s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM student_has_badge
                 WHERE studentnumber = s.studentnumber
                 AND badge_id = 61);
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't need the word NOT. Just the parameter of <> or =!

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.studentnumber, 
                s.firstname, 
                s.lastname 

FROM students s 
JOIN student_has_badge shb ON s.studentnumber = shb.studentnumber 
WHERE 
shb.badge_id <> 61
```

Comment: But this doesn't necessarily returns students that don't have the badge

Comment: You're right. I misread the OP's question. I read his question as "how do I not get the value of badge ID 61". In this particular case, @Gordon Linoff already answered the OP